# Reading a file returns <nil>

Tags: file, go

I am trying to read the content of a file using below code

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
)

func main() {
    // get the file names
    fileList := os.Args[1:]
    fmt.Println(fileList[0])
    // open the file 
    //f, err := os.Open(fileList[0])
    f, err := os.Open(fileList[0])
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Received error while opening file", os.Stderr, err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Reading from file via args. ")
        input := bufio.NewScanner(f)
        for input.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(input.Text())
        }

    }
    defer f.Close()

    f1, err1 := os.Open("./sample.txt")
    if err1 == nil {
        fmt.Println("Received error while opening file", os.Stderr, err1)
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Reading from static file. ")
        input1 := bufio.NewScanner(f1)
        for input1.Scan() {
            fmt.Println(input1.Text())
        }

    }
    defer f1.Close()
}
```

I am getting below error

```
· ~/read_from_file $ go run main.go sample.txt
sample.txt
Received error while opening file &{0xc0000a20c0} <nil>
Received error while opening file &{0xc0000a20c0} <nil>

· ~/read_from_file $
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your error checks are backwards, e.g.

```
    if err == nil {
        fmt.Println("Received error while opening file", os.Stderr, err)
    } else {
```

should be !=

```
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Received error while opening file", os.Stderr, err)
    } else {
```

Comment: aah!, How did I miss that. Thank you.